# Emphasis doesn't work correctly with comments at SE Code Review

Tags: bug, design

I've noticed that the markdown emphasis (`_emphasized text_`) doesn't seem to render correctly at SE Code Review (comments).

Example markdown:

`_Emphasized text_`

renders as

Emphasized text

I'd expect that text rendered in italics like described [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#emphasis).

Same for `**`, `***` markers.

Is that by (css) design, or just a bug?

I'm using Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Works just fine on my machine. _This part is in italics with markdown_

Comment: You might want to include screen captures so that we see what you see. Right now we don't, what we see is good as it is ;-)

Comment: Nice to know that this now effects Chrome...